# Creating a file from a absolute path, which is containing a german umlaut

Tags: java, file, utf-8, java-11

I have a problem with creating a file from a absolute path, which is containing a german umlaut. (Working on windows)
This is a example code:

```
 public void createFile(String path) {
      System.out.println("Path: " + path);  
      final File myPathFile = new File(path)
      if(!myPathFile.isFile()){
          System.out.println("No file");
      }
```

Log results:

```
Path: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MeinOrdner\Z_Überdenken\check.txt
No file
```

I tried to rename the  folder to Z_Ueberdenken and adjusted the path variable as well.
Then it worked perfectly. So the problem is the umlaut `Ü`. How can I fix this?

Comment: which filesystem do you use? does the file show up correctly in command prompt with the `dir` command? What is the filename when you do a `new File("C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MeinOrdner").list()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.File: accessing files with invalid filename encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775758/java-io-file-accessing-files-with-invalid-filename-encodings)

Comment: @cyberbrain Im working on windows. The file shows up correctly in the command pompt with `dir`. `.list()` returns  [Z_�berdenken]

Comment: BTW `new File(path)` does **not** create the file - it is just a path; and `File#isFile` will return `false` for a non existing file ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html) of `File`: "An abstract representation of file and directory **pathnames**." - emphasis added)

Comment: Windows supports multiple file systems, so still the interesting thing for me would be, what file system you use. IIRC the encoding of filenames could depend on that. Testing here with a (German) Windows 10, I get the correct name with `dir` and Java on a NTFS filesystem.

Comment: @cyberbrain Im also using NTFS. I Also get the correct name with dir. But .list() returns [Z_�berdenken]

Comment: maybe you must call `myPathFile.createNewFile();` to really create a new file on the disk (not just a *pathname*... as I already indicated) only if the directory already exists, otherwise it must be created too -- but posted code is sure not the code being executed, so hard to know if there are no other problems...

Comment: ( "*rename the file to Z_Ueberdenken.txt*"  ?? But `Z_Überdenken` in given path is a folder, not a file )

Comment: How did you verify what `.list()` returns? Printing to the console bears a potentially lossy conversion on its own.

Answer (score 0):

First, some basics of the `java.io.File` class:

- To create a directory use method `mkdir()`.
- To create a file use method `createNewFile()`.
- To check whether a file or directory already exists use method `exists()`.
- When creating a file, its parent directory must already exist. For example, if creating file **D:\Z_Überdenken\check.txt**, the directory **Z_Überdenken** must already exist; method `createNewFile()` will not create it for you.

Given that, creating directories and files is a straightforward process using the `File` class. Here's a working example:

```
package umlaut;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Umlaut {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String dirPath = "d:\\temp\\Z_Überdenken2"; // Directory name includes "Ü"
        String filePath = dirPath + "\\test4.txt";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) { // Create parent directory for new files.
            new Umlaut().createDir(dirPath);
        }
        if (dir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Is " + dirPath + " a file? " + dir.isFile());
            System.out.println("Is " + dirPath + " a directory? " + dir.isDirectory());
            new Umlaut().createFile(filePath);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to create directory " + dirPath);
        }
    }

    public boolean createDir(String path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Directory to be created: " + path);
        File myPathFile = new File(path);
        return myPathFile.mkdir();
    }

    public void createFile(String path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("File to be created: " + path);
        File myPathFile = new File(path);
        if (myPathFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Not creating " + myPathFile + " because it already exists.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Creation of file " + myPathFile + (myPathFile.createNewFile() ? " successful." : " failed."));
        }
        System.out.println("Is " + path + " a file? " + myPathFile.isFile());
        System.out.println("Is " + path + " a directory? " + myPathFile.isDirectory());
    }
}
```

This is the console output:

```
Is d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2 a file? false
Is d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2 a directory? true
File to be created: d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2\test4.txt
Creation of file d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2\test4.txt successful.
Is d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2\test4.txt a file? true
Is d:\temp\Z_Überdenken2\test4.txt a directory? false
```

Notes:

- The code provided in the question was not doing anything to create a physical directory or file. Simply passing a path to one of the constructors of `File` using `final File myPathFile = new File(path)` will instantiate a `File` object, but will not create a physical file on disk.
- I don't think that the use of an umlaut in the directory name is relevant. At least it was not an issue for me. But what does matter is whether or not the `File` you are trying to create already exists, so allow for that in your code.
- My environment was JDK 11 on Windows 10, using locale *English (United States)*.
- I did not need to configure anything with respect to my locale, use of UTF-8 or encoding, and I did not provide any compiler or run time options. Everything worked fine using default settings.
- I noticed an article titled [How to save text files in Java with umlauts](https://blog.dotmaui.com/2018/10/18/how-to-save-text-files-in-java-with-umlauts/) which may be of interest. It's not directly relevant to your problem because it relates to a file's content rather than it's name, but it does offer a completely different approach for file creation without using the `File` class.